# How to create form twig templates for a custom FormType?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig, symfony-forms

Given a Symfony 2.8 project, in a form i want to use a more complex type which consists of 4 text-input-fields (the reasons for this are the user input of opening times per week day).

**My Question:**

How can i define a custom twig template to this type having multiple form-elements in it? How does symfony know, which template belongs to which type?
I read the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-a-template-for-the-field), but they are mismatching the labels and names that they don't fit together.

**What I've done so far:**

I created the following type:

```
/**
 * Class OpeningType
 */
class OpeningType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('from', 'text', [
            'label' => '',
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => '08:00']
        ]);
        $builder->add('until', 'text', [
            'label' => '',
            'attr' => ['placeholder' => '18:00']
        ]);
    }
}
```

For the first try, i only added two text fields here.

The type is registered as a service:

```
example.form.type.opening:
    class: Example\MainBundle\Form\Type\OpeningType
    tags:
        - { name: form.type }
```

... and added this way to the main form:

```
        ->add('opening_monday', OpeningType::class, ['label' => 'Monday'])
```

How to achieve to use a custom widget as twig template for this custom type?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link in the doc to customize for theming :
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field or
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig

What you can do "locally":

```
{# /views/Controller/action.html.twig #}

{% block _{ form prefix }_opening_monday_row %}

    {# customize theme here #}

{% endblock %}

{% form_theme form _self %}

...

{{ form_row(form.opening_monday) }}
```

the prefix is by default the form name 'form' and the field name, here 'open_monday', you can customize it in the form builder :

```
$builder->add('opening_monday', OpeningType::class, ['label' => 'Monday', 'block_name' => 'custom_prefix'])
```

or globally in `app/config.yml` :

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - form/custom_fields.html.twig
```

and in `app/Resources/views/form/custom_fields.html.twig` :

```
{% block custom_type_name_raw %}
    {# customise "form_row" here #}
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_type_name_label %}
    {# customise "form_label" here #}
{% endblock %}

{% block custom_type_name_widget %}
    {# customise "form_widget" here #}
{% endblock %}
```

needs following method in `CustomFormType` :

```
// Symfony 2.8+
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return "custom_type_name";
}

// before 2.7 included
public function getName()
{
    return "custom_type_name";
}
```

Comment: the twig-file will not be loaded in generell. i guess there has to be a special name pattern or a registration somewhere in config files?

Comment: you mean this http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#twig ?

Comment: yes, thanks. in between i found by myself this missing step :)

Comment: updated answer for general theming and local theming

Answer (score -1):

I can answer myself :)

**1. in config.yml define form_themes-template:**

```
twig:
    form_themes:
        - form/fields.html.twig
```

**2. create the file mentioned above with the following content:**

```
{% block opening_widget %}
       {# write your form stuff here #}
{% endblock %}
```

The block-name is "opening_widget" because of "OpeningType" is the name of the type. It can be overwritten by a method something with getPrefixName (or something like that), but this is not the question here.